# PHP Session expiration time

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

`php.ini` contains this line:

```
session.cache_expire = 180
```

Which as far as I know means that session expires in 180 minutes. If I visit a PHP page 60 minutes after session was created - will my session expiration time relapse to 180 minutes again?

or would it still be 120 minutes? if 120 minutes - then at that point how would I extend it?

Comment: **`cache`** `_expire` I don't know much about php, but I found the word cache.

Comment: Are you aware this setting is related to the HTTP `Expires` header and has nothing to do with the lifetime of the session on the server?

Answer (score 0):

It's 180 minutes after the last request, so provided you (or your visitor) submits requests with the same cookie every 179 minutes, your session will remain active.